# How to approach this hackerrank puzzle?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, sorting

I have a string [5:10, 1:2] where I have to compact this string and sort at same time. 
I used this regex expression

```
String[] strRange = ranges.replaceAll("\\s", "").replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]"," ").split(" ");
```

to convert it into simple string array of numbers`[5,10,1,2]`.

I did some string to integer manipulation so that I can store that string array into `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Somehow I sorted list using Collections.sort() [1,2,5,10].

What I need is to convert back that sorted `Arraylist` into `[1:2,5:10]`.

Can anyone help me brainstorm this issue?

Comment: Simply iterate through your array and build a string. Put : or , according to modula of a counter

Comment: @hsnkhrmn If you dont mind can you please elaborate the approach of your logic. I just tried simple  approach 'arr.get(j)+":"+arr.get(j+1)+"," +arr.get(j+2)+":"+arr.get(arr.size()-1))' and it worked for given string. Thanks.

Comment: (What _is_ the idea to first replace one pattern by a fixed string and immediately using that string in a split()? Just using `ranges.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]")` should do the trick, but consider using [`Stream<String> Pattern.splitAsStream(CharSequence input)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not post it to comment section. Please see below:

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);

int i = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
for (int value : integers) {
    sb.append((i == 0) ? "" : (i % 2 == 0 ? "," : ":")).append(value);
    i++;
}
sb.append("]");
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Output is:

> [1:2,3:4]